# How can I test recursive http requests that have a delay?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-httpclient

I have a somewhat complex situation where, do to backend implementation, I need to poll the backend until either

1. I get a success status from the BE
2. I get a fail status from the BE
3. I get onGoing for longer than my retry count (client side TO)

The code works, and testing against the backend succeeded in all three situations. I have also succeeded in testing the first and second situations, if the result is instantaneous (mocking the response of complete / fail immediately, without getting `onGoing` in the middle). However, I have not been able to test the third case. I got different errors with each attempt, so now I am turning to the collective mind of S.O. for some help :-)

ts file:

```
doAction(content): Observable<resPassType> {
    return this.postAction(content) // private function that just calls HTTP Post at url1, and returns an actionId for polling
      .pipe(concatMap(action => this.poll(action))); // see below
}

private poll(action, retryCount = config.retryCount): Observable<resPassType>{
    return time(config.retryTime).pipe(switchMap(() =>
      this.getActionStatus(action) // private function that calls HTTP get at url2/action.id
      .pipe(concatMap ( res=> {
        retryCount--;
        if(retryCount < 0)
            return throwError('Action Timed Out'); // this is essentially what I want to test
        switch(res.action.state.toLowerCase()) {
            case 'completed':
                return of(resPassTypeData);//taken from within res.action. Successfully tested
            case 'failed':
                return throwError('Action Failed'); // successfully tested
            case 'ongoing':
                return this.poll(res.action, retryCount)
            default:
                return throwError('unexpeceted action state');
            }
        }))));
}
```

Seeing the successful tests may help you help me, so included here is the test for failure

```
it('should throw error if action failed', fakeAsync(()=>{
    const mockGetActionResponse = {'action' : {'id' : mockActionId, state: 'Failed' }};
    
    service.doAction(mockContent).subscribe(
        () => {},
        err => expect(err).toEqual('Action Failed');
    );

    const postCall = httpTestingController.expectOne(url1);
    expect(postCall.request.method).toEqual('POST');
    expect(postCall.request.body).toEqual(mockContent);

    postCall.flush(mockPostActionResponse);

    tick(config.retryTime);

    const getCall = httpTestingController.expectOne(url2/mockActionId);
    expect(getCall .request.method).toEqual('Get');

    getCall.flush(mockGetActionResponse );
}));
```

This test works. How can I write the test for case 3? Writing the same test and changing the state to `onGoing` and changing the error expectation left me with the error

> error expected no open requests found 1

My hunch is that is has something to do with the recursion or the delay or something, since this is the only test case where `poll` gets called more than once. Any leads would be greatly appreciated :-)

**EDIT**
Code has been updated thanks to comments and improvements from @Andrei. Issue still persists.

Comment: a funny thing is how you are using `delay` operator The result is: you are requesting data just after calling `poll` method, but then you are just delaying the handling of it. So lets the data is downloaded on the client after 1 second, and user sees the result only after 1 + delay seconds . I think this is not intended.  I believe to make your test you can use loop `for(let i = 0; i < config.retryCount; i++) { controller.expectOne(url).flush({... satte: 'ongoing'});  }`

Comment: I tried your `for` method, but that just resulted in an additional error of `expeceted one matching request for criteria "Match url: url2/mockActionId", found none` (in addition to the error mentioned in the question)

Comment: `timer(config.retryDelay).pipe(switchMap(() => makeRequest(..)))` is better. I believe you could try `fakeAsync` test and `tick` between requests to start a new one `for(...){expectOne(...).flush(...);tick();}`

Comment: changing to `timer` made all the tests fail, but maybe that is a good thing.. I will look into `fakeAsync` and `tick`

Comment: edited the code, and fixed the previously-working tests, but the tricky one's solution still eludes me

Comment: tick should flush the timer for you now. try to put tick before the expect

Comment: I did - the error that results is `1 periodic timer(s) still in the queue)`

Comment: that is strange. it shouldn't happen if the stream errored, and you got your error callback called. maybe 1 more tick is required from the logic point of view? so for(;i **<=** config.retryCount ;) instead of just **<**

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have done the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found by @Andrei in the comments.

Working code now looks like this:

```
it('should throw error if action timed out',()=>{
    const mockGetActionResponse = {'action' : {'id' : mockActionId, state: 'onGoing' }};

    service.doAction(mockContent).subscribe(
        () => {},
        err => expect(err).toEqual('Action Timed Out');
    );

    const postCall = httpTestingController.expectOne(url1);
    expect(postCall.request.method).toEqual('POST');
    expect(postCall.request.body).toEqual(mockContent);

    postCall.flush(mockPostActionResponse);

    for( let i=0; i<config.retryCount; i++) {
        tick(config.delayTime);
        const getCall = httpTestingController.expectOne(url2);
        expect(getCall.request.method).toEqual('GET');
        getCall.flush(mockGetActionResponse)
    }
})
```